# Can't add Route to Blazor Server Side

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Ill try to register route via

```
services.AddRazorPages(options => options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/counter", "/c"));
```

in `ConfigureServices`.

I can't just add `@page "/c"`, because I plan to pull up this addresses from the config file.

But, when I try to visit `.../c`, it says that the page was not found, `.../counter` works. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is mentioned in the Counter.razor file with `@page`?

Comment: @viveknuna `@page "/counter"`, i use default blazor project to reproduce this.

Comment: Then why are you expecting it to work with `.../c`?

Comment: Because I added a PageRoute which should redirect from `c` to `counter`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-a-page-route
Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: you need to provide the relevant code

Comment: @viveknuna https://github.com/SKProCH/BlazorRedirectSample this is the default blazor template

Comment: @SKProCH blazor is different from razor pages, it does not support that method, could you please detailed your needs?May be there is a work round

Comment: @JerryCai i want load address from config file and make redirect from this address to static page

Comment: In the end, do you want to dynamically generate resources? For example generate a voice room and then provide a link to it? You might want to take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a valid reason for resorting to `AddPageRoute`, but you haven't said, so why don't you just do this:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@page "/c"
@page "/co"
@page "/cou"

<h1>Counter</h1>
```

Unlike Razor, Blazor takes multiple `@page` directives.

Comment: Yeah, this is can be solution, but I plan to pull up this addresses from the config file, so I can't set them statically. Also i edited question text to include this info

Answer (score 1):

RazorPages != Blazor.

Your route does not apply to Blazor pages.

When there was an `.AddRazorPages()` in the original template code then that was from using Individual Accounts. You can add a route for the Login, Logout and Account pages this way. Not for /Counter.

Answer (score 0):

> i want load address from config file and make redirect from this address to static page

I made a demo for you:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config

<button class="btn-primary" @onclick="RedirectTo">Go</button>

@code {
    void RedirectTo()
    {
        var address = @config["address"];
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(address);
    }

//Use this if you want to redirect immediately without some trigger event
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var address = @config["address"]; //get address from config file
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(address); //redirect
    }
}
```

Address configs in appsettings.json as an example:

```
{
  "address": "/counter",
  "Logging":...,
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: OK, but this still doesn't make much sense.  Your example works.  I'm assuming you want to change the `@page` directive to include some data from configure, but how?  In your example you're just navigating to counter.